# How to combine duplicate consecutive entries in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database which holds the callhistory and looks like this

```
 Phonenumber             date/time

 6822311319     |   2014-04-21/ 12:10

 6822311319     |   2014-04-21/ 12:05

 9195432313     |   2014-04-21/ 11:10

 4324543234     |   2014-04-21/ 10:05

 6822311319     |   2014-04-21/ 06:10

 5344653244     |   2014-04-21/ 05:05

 5344653244     |   2014-04-21/ 04:10

 5344653244     |   2014-04-21/ 01:05

 7866545543     |   2014-04-21/ 00:10

 5344653244     |   2014-04-21/ 00:05
```

The requirement is that if two call events are from same phone number and are sequential to each other, then only the latest call from that number shall be stored and displayed.

I would like to know if I can run a query which can give me the output as below:

```
 Phonenumber           date/time

 6822311319     |   2014-04-21/ 12:10

 9195432313     |   2014-04-21/ 11:10

 4324543234     |   2014-04-21/ 10:05

 6822311319     |   2014-04-21/ 06:10

 5344653244     |   2014-04-21/ 05:05

 7866545543     |   2014-04-21/ 00:10

 5344653244     |   2014-04-21/ 00:05
```

Answer (score 1):

Without common table expressions or analytic functions the query isn't very elegant, but this seems to work;

```
SELECT a.phonenumber, a.dt
FROM (
  SELECT phonenumber, dt, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable m2 WHERE m2.dt<m.dt) cnt 
  FROM myTable m
) a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT phonenumber, dt, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable m2 WHERE m2.dt<m.dt) cnt 
  FROM myTable m
) b
ON a.cnt+1=b.cnt
WHERE a.phonenumber<>b.phonenumber OR b.phonenumber IS NULL
ORDER BY a.dt DESC;
```

(Sadly, SQLfiddle seems a little tired right now or I'd post a fiddle)